# how to push 100s of docker images to the docker hub at once?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am trying to find a way how to push 100s of images to the docker hub in a single short. Is there a better and efficient way to do this?

```
alpine:1.0.0.0
alpine:2.0.0.0
.
..
...
alpine:100.0.0.0
```

there are 100 images. I am looking for the best way to push all the images to the docker hub.

Comment: Do you mean in parallel? Or some other automation?

Comment: Better than what? You didn't provide any base method or code for expanding on.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

[moby issue 9132](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9132) seems to indicate that you can push in parallel:

> this was included in the 1.10.3 release, but requires a registry 2.3.x.

You would need to:

- thread your docker push
- change the `--max-concurrent-uploads int` of the [docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#miscellaneous-options) to 100 at least, in order to maximize the number of parallel pushed (by default limited to 5)
- make sure your network upload capacity can handle that kind of parallel queries!

Beside that, parallel push is requested since 2014 (see [issue 7336](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7336))
There is [PR 458](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/458), but...

> This change doesn't not address the fundamental problems that are brought up when requesting this feature.
>   The idea behind multiple push/pull arguments is that they are parallelized, but this simply performs them in sequence. This design provides no advantage over `for i in images; do docker push $i; done`.

So you still need to script the threading of `docker push`.